# Altering a value in R using conditional logic

Tags: r

I have a dataset of albums and I'd like to change specific genres of certain albums to a broader genre.

```
> AlbumData$Genre
[1] Pop        Rock       Rock       Soundtrack Rock       Rock      
[7] Soundtrack Rock       Country    Rock       Pop        Rock      
[13] Pop        Rock       Rock       Pop        Soundtrack Pop       
[19] Pop        Rock       Pop        Rock       Rock       Rock      
[25] Soundtrack Metal      Grunge     Rock       Rock       Metal
Levels: Country Grunge Metal Pop Rock Soundtrack
```

This is the output when I call my Genre column. I'd like to replace "Grunge" and "Metal" with "Rock." Additionally, I'd like to replace "Soundtrack" and "Country" with "Other".

I created this conditional logic statement for the first task I am trying to accomplish

```
for(k in 1:30){if(AlbumData$Genre[k] == 'Metal' | AlbumData$Genre[k] == 'Grunge'){AlbumData$Genre[k] <- 'Rock'}}
```

This worked successfully. I alter it to complete my second task.

```
for(j in 1:30){if(AlbumData$Genre[j] == 'Soundtrack' | AlbumData$Genre[j] == 'Country'){AlbumData$Genre[j] <- 'Other'}}
```

All I've changed is what is inside the quotes, but it doesn't work and I get the following error.

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, j, value = "Other") :
    invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Multiple times. I assume this is because "Other" was not in Levels earlier on. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Factors don't take kindly to introducing new levels. Just convert to `character`, make all your edits, then (if you want) convert back to `factor`.

Comment: Also, a nicer looking syntax, and typically faster method would be `ifelse(AlbumData$Genre %in% c('Metal', 'Grunge'), 'Rock', AlbumData$Genre)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the additional factor and replace

```
AlbumData$Original <- AlbumData$Genre
AlbumData$Genre[AlbumData$Genre %in% c("Grunge", "Metal")] <- "Rock"
levels(AlbumData$Genre) <- c(levels(AlbumData$Genre), "Other")
AlbumData$Genre[AlbumData$Genre %in% c("Soundtrack", "Country")] <- "Other"
```

As mentioned in the comments, the factors can be converted to characters first

```
AlbumData$char <- levels(AlbumData$Genre)[AlbumData$Genre]
AlbumData$char[AlbumData$char %in% c("Grunge", "Metal")] <- "Rock"
AlbumData$char[AlbumData$char %in% c("Soundtrack", "Country")] <- "Other"
AlbumData$char <- as.factor(AlbumData$char)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with adding a level. I also appreciate the cleaner syntax. levels(AlbumData$Genre) <- c(levels(AlbumData$Genre), "Other") was the key line that I needed.